# How to set tab key to indent text on nvim without errors?

Tags: vim, settings, indentation

This is my setting for "tab" indentation in nvim

```
nnoremap <Tab> >>_
nnoremap <S-Tab> <<_
inoremap <S-Tab> <C-D>
vnoremap <Tab> >gv
vnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

But the problem is whenever I restart my nvim and try to press the tab to indent text nvim report the error  `E481: No range allowed`. When I tried to open the setting file and sourced that file by the command `:so%`. The indentation turned out to be perfectly worked. I don't want to open and source the vim setting file every time I want to indent text.

Can anyone help me with this annoying issue?

This is my full vim setting: https://pastebin.com/wG2NWGac

Answer (score 1):

From `:help e481`:

> A range was specified for an Ex command that doesn't permit one.

Those mappings don't use Ex commands so they can't throw that error. The fact that you have to source the script manually tells me that some other script is sourced after or instead of the desired one.

Start Vim as usual and execute the following command:

```
:verbose nmap <Tab>
```

to see where `<Tab>` is mapped.

---

Since we are at it…

- Lines 1-2 are redundant. Keep line 2.
- Lines 20-27 don't do what you think they do. Try `10j`, `10h`, `10k`, and `10l` instead. Moreover, `<S-j>` is just `J` so there is no need for that opaque notation, here.
- Same remark about the notation for lines 37-40.
- `J`, `H`, `K`, `L`, `W`, `c` are all pretty useful normal mode commands that you shouldn't override. Removing features from Vim is not exactly a constructive approach to learning it.

  See `:help J`, `:help H`, `:help K`, `:help L`, `:help W`, and `:help c`.
- Your use of recursive/non-recursive mapping commands is inconsistent.
- Line 45, there is no built-in `:BW` Ex command. Did you mean `:bw`?

Comment: Oh, when I typed ```:verbose nmap <Tab>```, it turned out that my <tab> key had been mapped to ```NERDTREEFIND```. That's the reason why my indentation didn't work. Thank you very much for your command.